# AS3 - Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have no idea what is causing the error. I'm sure its very obvious.
(See comments below).

```
package src.main{

    import src.tilespack.Tile;

    public class Main{

        public var tile:Tile;

        public function Main{
            var t:Tile = Tile.tiles[0]; //Error here

            trace(Tile); //This will also cause an error
        }
```

Tile:

```
package src.tilespack{

    public static var tiles:Array = [];

    public static var floorTile:Tile = new FloorTile(0); //Causes an error in FloorTile Class

    public var bitmapData:BitmapData;

    public function Tile(bitmapData:BitmapData, ID:int)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        tiles[ID] = this;
        this.bitmapData = bitmapData;
    }

}
```

FloorTile:

```
package src.tilespack{
    import src.gfx.Assets;
    import src.tilespack.Tile;

    public class FloorTile extends Tile{ //Error here

        public function FloorTile(ID:int){
            super(Assets.floorTileData, ID);
        }
    }
}
```

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object
>   reference.

Comment: I don't got a defintive answer, but shouldn't tiles be more than just []? Later on you set tiles[0] = this; at the Tile constructor. But tiles[0] does not jet exist.  public static var tiles:Array = new Array(1); works in my head. Switch to tiles.push(this) for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I had already tried that. Debugging shows me that the the error is here `public class FloorTile extends Tile` . Even if i just `trace(Tile)` I still get the same error.

Comment: var t:Tile = new Tile;   trace(Tile.tiles[0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed few problems in your code:

1) The file **Tile** doesn't have a definition of class. Probably, this is just a typo, but anyway, this file should look something like:

```
package src.tilespack
{
    public class Tile
    {
        public static var tiles:Array = [];

        public static var floorTile:Tile = new FloorTile(0); //Causes an error in FloorTile Class

        public var ID:int;
        public var bitmapData:BitmapData;

        public function Tile(bitmapData:BitmapData, ID:int)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            tiles[ID] = this;
            this.bitmapData = bitmapData;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Your code has something like "recursive linkage" (sorry, I don't know the official term). Your class **Tile** has the static variable **floorTile**, and it tries to create an instance of the **FloorTile** class, which itself extends the class **Tile**.

So we have a situation, when the class **Tile** tries to use the class **FloorTile** (because static variables should be instantiated during the first class use), and the class **FloorTile** tries to use the class **Tile**. And it's a problem.

You may either remove static variable of the type **FloorTile** or change code of the class **Tile** to prevent usage of the class **FloorTile** before the class **Tile** is prepared to work. Here an example of the second approach:

```
package src.tilespack
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;

    public class Tile
    {
        public static var tiles:Array = [];

        private static var _floorTile:Tile;
        public static function get floorTile():Tile
        {
            if (!Tile._floorTile)
            {
                Tile._floorTile = new FloorTile(0);
            }

            return Tile._floorTile;
        }

        public var ID:int;
        public var bitmapData:BitmapData;

        public function Tile(bitmapData:BitmapData, ID:int)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            tiles[ID] = this;
            this.bitmapData = bitmapData;
        }
    }
}
```